# How can I make a desktop wallpaper slideshow with my own images?

Tags: 14.04, desktop-background, slideshow

So I know Ubuntu has a slideshow option in the wallpaper settings, containing all default wallpapers for that release. This means that the functionality is already there and actually working! But I can't seem to find a way to create my own slideshow with my own collection of wallpapers. Does someone know how I can do this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to check out [Variety](http://peterlevi.com/variety/).

> Variety is packed with great features, yet slim and easy to use. It
>   can use local images or automatically download wallpapers from lots of
>   online sources, allows you to rotate them on a regular interval, and
>   provides easy ways to separate the great images from the junk. Variety
>   can also display wise and funny quotations or a nice digital clock on
>   the desktop.

To install -

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install variety`